# jQuery Form Processing With PHP to MYSQL Database Using $.ajax Request

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

in my form i am using an option Bloodgroup if user input is O+
mydatastring will be like this

```
name=phani&age=13&sex=male&bloodgroup=**o+**&phone=7864987540&email=phaniandu4@gmail.com&city=akividu&area=donka street&pin=534235
```

In my database the value is storing as O and not as O+

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: We need the actual PHP code that stores the variables in the db.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is a url. If so, use urlencode('O+') and enter its output (O%2B) in the url. Before entering the data in the database use urldecode() to change 'O%2B' to 'O+.
Another thing you could do is assign each bloodgroup a number (O+ -> 0, A+ -> 1, ..., AB- -> 7) and then use a switch in your php code so that if bloodgroup == 1 enter O+ in the database and so forth.